# How should I wash Ventile clothing?

Tags: cleaning

My Ventile jacket is getting a bit dirty. Is there anything special I need to know when washing it, or will a regular washing liquid and low temperature do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [ventile.co.uk](http://www.ventile.co.uk/specification.htmlx):

> Ventile can be either dry-cleaned as detailed below or hand washed
>   using [Grangers 30 Degree Cleaner](http://www.grangers.co.uk/product.cfm?cat=14&productid=1)
>
> - Professional dry-cleaning in: perchloroethylene, hydrocarbons. Mild cleaning process with stringent limitation of added humidity and/or
>     mechanical action and/or temperature. Commercial stain removers on a
>     solvent base may be used with some restrictions. A trail on a
>     concealed part of the article is advisable beforehand.
> - We recommend hand washing  in Grangers Pure Liquid  Soap for Ventile , using the following procedure :
>
>   1. Gently brush or sponge off any dirt or grit.
>   2. Close the zip fastener
>   3. Turn the garment inside out
>   4. Hand wash in Grangers Pure Liquid Soap for Ventile.
>   5. Ensure all residue soap is removed from the garment, re-rinse if necessary.
>   6. Re-shape the garment on a hanger and allow to dry naturally avoiding direct  sunlight.
>   7. Iron carefully on a warm setting – this reactivates the DWR treatment.

Comment: Hi Mr. Wizard. At least in my browser, these links are both dead. They do lead to the Ventile site, though, so perhaps you can find where on the site the information can be found, and replace the links. Thanks.

Comment: This is an excellent example of why we discourage link-only answers. Even if the links are dead and not replaceable, the answer still has useful information.